# How to make post request without passing its value?

Tags: swift3, http-post

I'm having a POST Request like below codes.I'm not passing any body with it.**But how to make this request dynamic it means it should accept any mobile number which i'have entered in my mobiletextfield not the specific one like 0123456789**

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "myurl/register?mobileno=0123456789")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `number` to be value of mobile textfield:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "myurl/register?mobileno=\(number)")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

Comment: hey and how to pass the parameters without textfield?. I mean having a scenario in which I have to pass the mobile number and otp for verification how should I do ?

Comment: @TheMiss I think you can wrapper it as a function, let the number to be a parameter. You can call this function after the verification is passed.

Comment: @ 李骏骁 hey it would be great help of mine if you will try to solve my this question. thanks in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985996/how-to-create-a-multiple-autocompletion-textfields-which-works-as-a-filter-in-sw